# Dotnet 5 MVC with keycloak only working locally

Tags: c#, .net, keycloak

I'm trying to use keycloak with a dotnet 5 MVC app. It's basically just 1 page I want to protect.

After a few hours of testing stuff I now get it to work with localhost, if I try to access the resource I go to the keycloak login and after a successful login I go back to the same URL I tried to access originally. But when I host it on IIS it doesn't work anymore, after a successful login I get redirected to the same URL but with /signin-oidc appended and a status 500.

Keycloak is behind a nginx reverse proxy so maybe that has to do with it?

IIS eventlog shows the following error.

```
Category: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.ExceptionHandlerMiddleware
EventId: 1
SpanId: 7eafa51ac49c4546
TraceId: bfceaf44d2f5fd438b04aaf4bdf93170
ParentId: 0000000000000000
RequestId: 8000010a-0000-f300-b63f-84710c7967bb
RequestPath: /signin-oidc

An unhandled exception has occurred while executing the request.

Exception: 
System.Exception: An error was encountered while handling the remote login.
 ---> System.Exception: OpenIdConnectAuthenticationHandler: message.State is null or empty.
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.RemoteAuthenticationHandler`1.HandleRequestAsync()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder.Extensions.UsePathBaseMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.ExceptionHandlerMiddleware.<Invoke>g__Awaited|6_0(ExceptionHandlerMiddleware middleware, HttpContext context, Task task)
```

This is my code at the moment.

```
services.AddAuthentication(options =>
            {
                options.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
                options.DefaultSignInScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
                options.DefaultChallengeScheme = OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
            })
            .AddCookie(options =>
            {
                //options.Cookie.SameSite = SameSiteMode.None;
                //options.Cookie.SecurePolicy = CookieSecurePolicy.Always;
                //options.Cookie.IsEssential = true;

            })
            .AddOpenIdConnect(options =>
            {
                
                options.ClientId = clientId;
                options.Authority = keylcoakUrl;
                options.ClientSecret = clientSecret;
                options.ResponseType = OpenIdConnectResponseType.Code;
                options.SaveTokens = true;
                options.SignInScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;

                if (Environment.IsDevelopment())
                {   // to make sure this is only used during development
                options.RequireHttpsMetadata = false;

                }
            });
```

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

Regarding your message, State is empty. In accordance with Oauth2, the state is the parameter of proving initiated authorization request.

So, firstly your server sends client_id (where to authenticate) and a state, in return it gets a login page. After exchanging your username and password to code, the server must return the state as well, for a reason of preventing XSRF attacks. So, possibly somehow, the server does not send a state or don't get it from Keycloak.

Answer (score 1):

I was getting this error **System.Exception: An error was encountered while handling the remote login**; in my case, it was because I lacked the code below. Add it in the Startup > ConfigureServices().

```cs
services.Configure<ForwardedHeadersOptions>(options =>
        {
            options.ForwardedHeaders =
                ForwardedHeaders.XForwardedFor | ForwardedHeaders.XForwardedProto;

            options.KnownNetworks.Clear();
            options.KnownProxies.Clear();
        });
```

Because the app is behind an Nginx proxy, I guess it needs some help regarding the **ForwardedHeadersOptions**.